# What happens if I get the reference of a variable passed with an ampersand?

Tags: c++

Ok so lets say I have `function(int& myval)`, if in the body of that function I do `&myval` will that point to the parameter on the stack or the original value?

Comment: Your question seems a little off. What do you mean by " the parameter on the stack or the original pointer I passed in"? You didn't pass any pointers and since references don't have an address, you can only take the address of whatever it refers to

Comment: @Ayxan I've corrected the question

Comment: Since the parameter on the stack is an `int&` and the result of `&myval` is an `int*`, how could it point to the parameter on the stack? It has to point to an `int` since it's an `int*`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz My thinking was that `&myval` might mean 'give me a reference to the reference'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

References don't have an address, using the address-of operator `&` on a reference type will return the address of the variable that the reference is bound to.

Comment: So you're telling me that it'll give me the pointer I passed in right?

Comment: @faissaloo It'll give you whatever you passed in, yes.

Comment: @JoelBodenmann yes that's what I meant, which should've been clear from the OP asking about what pointer would be returned

Comment: When every you are dealing with a referenced object you can just forget it is a reference. Just act as if it was the actual object.

Answer (score 0):

As said by Sombrero Chicken, a reference doesn't have an address:
consider it like an "alias" of the referenced variable, just another name to reference it ( nomen omen)